# Getting ant to put dependent jars in ./lib

Tags: java, ant, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I do I get `ant`  `jar` task to put the dependent jars in the directory `./lib` inside the jar?  Currently, `ant` puts those in `./`.

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile" description="generate the distribution">
   <jar jarfile="${dist.dir}/projectx-${version}.jar" basedir="${build.dir}" />
</target>
```

The reason being that Amazon Hadoop EMR with MapR seems to require this.

Comment: It seems to me that [ant jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested [zipfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) with a prefix to do this.

Comment: +1 Using this, I get all the dependent jars both in `./` and `./lib`... and do I get rid of those in './'?

Comment: I used a `delete` task currently. Couldn't a more subtle way of doing this.

Comment: You probably could use the implicit fileset of the `jar` task to exclude the jars, or perhaps the excludes parameter.  (Apologies for the short post, I was 'mobile'.)